# Where does Nautilus-actions configuration tool save actions?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, nautilus-actions

I want to use a command line, but don't know how this configuration looks like and where to save it.

Comment: `~/.local/share/file-manager/actions/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus-actions/tree/data/gconf-schemas/nautilus-actions-prefs.schemas.in), it uses [GConf](https://projects.gnome.org/gconf/) to store configuration. Gconf can be manipulated from the command line using [gconftool-2](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gconftool-2) but you do need to understand the schema because `gconftool` is pretty low-level and can't ensure that your changes are correct or consistent.

You might find it easier to use the nautilus action configuration tool to change an action and `gconftool` to see what gets changed than to make sense of the schema description directly.

Comment: Thanks, but can you provide a small code example?

Comment: Sorry, I can't without doing more work than you'd need to because I don't use nautilus-actions and try not to use gconftool if I can avoid it.

Comment: the actions can be exported in different formats by going to `tools: export aassistant`. Also, look at `Edit-Preferences-Export`.

Answer (score 2):

When they are exported  by going to `tools: export aassistant` (also, look at `Edit-Preferences-Export`) they contain Gconf settings, but at the same time the settings made in **nautilus action configuration tool** are `.desktop` files created in `/.local/share/file-manager/actions`, and those do not contain such settings, except some that stand for the upper levels of a tree-menu.

For example, after creating this setting in  **Nautilus action configuration tool**:

[image]

which gives this:

[image]

the upper level menus like "Subtitles" and "Download subtitles" contain lines like `ItemsList=3f0b618c-c6fe-436c-86a9-2ebd9b1a77dd;1601ae38-5d78-4214-aeef-b7feb9864fc7;d67b7f55-6b10-418b-bfe8-eb9d4e5e7732;66242038-c8b1-414f-9ef2-4d5bb831a027;`, which are gconf settings that cannot really be edited manually in the text file, while the lowest level items (the actions themselves - EN, RO, FR, etc) do not have such code lines and can be edited.